# List index out of range in indented for loops

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that searches a list of strings, using a second list. The first list is a list of random jumbled up letters and the second is a list of words. The program is supposed to detect whether a word in the each word in the second list can be found in any of the strings in the first. If it is, then the word that was found is added to an empty, third list.

```
counter = 0
for a in FirstList:
    for b in SecondList:
        if SecondList[counter] in FirstList[counter]:
            ThirdList += [SecondList[counter]]
        counter += 1
        if counter >= len(SecondList):
            break
return ThirdList
```

However, it throws up an error on the first if statement claiming that the list index is out of range. I don't quite understand what I am missing, because I am not editing the contents of any of the lists that I am iterating through, which is what the reason for this error was in other posts about the same error.

Comment: Since you have two nested loops, your counter will count from `0` to `len(first_list) * len(second_list)`.

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: As Guimoute noticed you probably need to put `counter = 0` inside the first loop, but it's hard to say for sure because we don't have a [mre]

Comment: Are you expecting `if counter >= len(SecondList): break` to break out of both loops?  It will only break out of the inner loop.  It makes sense to me that that's your problem, as that test seems to be protecting against the error you are getting.

Comment: You never use `a` nor `b`... Your two loops seem similar to just `for a, b in zip(FirstList, SecondList): if b in a: ThirdList.append(b)`

Comment: Please provide sample input and output so we know what your code is supposed to do, and what the incoming data looks like - or even better, a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should not iterate over the two lists. Your counter is exceding the amount of elements in both lists. If I understand well what you are trying to do, you could use the following code:

```
ThirdList = []
for word in SecondList:
  for random_word in FirstList:
    if word in random_word and word not in ThirdList:
      ThirdList.append(word)
return ThirdList
```

You can remove the second condition of the `if` statement if you have no problem with duplicate elements in ThirdList.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are you using a counter which should break at the size of SecondList, but if the FirstList is smaller "counter" will be out of bounds for the FirstList.

I think this may be closer to what you are trying to achieve:

```
ThirdList = [word for word in SecondList for string in FirstList if word in string]
```

This is a [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) which is running through both lists and outputting any values from the second list which appear in any of the values in the first list.

So for example with the code:

```
FirstList = ["aadada", "asdtest", "hasdk"]
SecondList = ["test", "data"]
ThirdList = [word for word in SecondList for string in FirstList if word in string]
print(ThirdList)
```

You would receive the output: "test" as test is found in the FirstList.

Comment: I see multiple things wrong with the OPs code, and multiple reasons that the logic might be leading to the error.  It may very well be the case that FirstList is always shorter than SecondList.  I don't think you should guess at an answer that may be wrong depending on information you don't have.  Better to make the OP clarify their question.